# How can I pass a variable from one .js file to another .js?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Symfony application with a menu that creates lashes and use a .js file to load into a div the ulr pointed to each menu option using the load () method. This .js is a variable that acts counter to reference each created tab. This idea can be seen in this example:

http://jsfiddle.net/JMMS_85/o7610t24/

```
$("#tabs-"+tabCounter).load($(this).attr('href'));
```

The URL that is loaded into the div has other links, so I created another .js file to block the original link to "preventDefault ()" and I have to reload these links in it earlier div, that is display the url of the new link in the same div, so I have to use the variable counter another .js file on it to know what is the actual div selected.

file1.js

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
$("#tabs").tabs();
   var tabCounter = 1;
   var cont =1;

        //Code creating the tabs omitted
 $(".container div a").on("click",function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); 

        tabTitle = $(this).attr("title"),
        addTab();
        $("#tabs-"+tabCounter).load($(this).attr('href'));
        tabCounter++;
        $("#tabs").tabs({active: $('.ui-tabs-nav li:last').index()});
  });
 });
```

file2.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {

       $("a").click( function(event)
        {
        event.preventDefault();            

        $("#tabs-"+tabCounter).load(this.href);
    });
```

My problem is how to use the counter variable first .js file to another file.

Comment: I see your example but I am having trouble following your paragraphs after the code. Can you reword it a bit? Oh, and what sebastien said.

Comment: this question no need to symfony2 tag

Comment: In the example I showed you load a text on each content of the tabs, but in my project url is loaded with the load method file1.js. THE problem is that the variable TabCounter use in file1.js use in the file2.js need to reference that we find tab to load all corresponding url in each div.

I added the two .js files to make it look lighter.

Comment: The thing to add the label Symfony2 is because simfony use in my project and so one option would be to use session variables to solve this problem, all I am new to symfony and does not use that.

Answer (score 4):

You can create the variable outside of functions.

Here you can see how JavaScript Scope works: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp

Answer (score 1):

You can also save the variable in the DOM using [jquery data](https://api.jquery.com/data/)

For example:

#### Setting the initial value

```
$('#tabs').data('counter', 1);
```

#### Retrieving the value

```
var tabCounter = $('#tabs').data('counter');
```

#### Incrementing the value

```
var tabCounter = $('#tabs').data('counter');
$('#tabs').data('counter', ++tabCounter);
```

#### Demo

http://jsfiddle.net/o7610t24/3/

Comment: I tried what you say and functions properly in the file1.js, but if I add in the file2.js "var TabCounter = $ ('# tabs') data ('counter')." to retrieve the value in file1.js not obtained. I'm new to all this and I do not know if things right, if you see that should work in file2.js please explain to me how it should do it, thanks.

Comment: Still not working. The problem did not have in the first .js file everything goes great, the problem is that I had to add another .js file pages to be loaded into the div for each tab and that's where I have to get it tab is active when loading the page to refer to the load () method the div is shown and none of the hidden. What I do not get is get the value of a variable from an external .js file to another .js.

Sorry, do not know if I explained well.

Comment: @Joseph why doesn't it work? What's the issue? can you post your code for what you tried in file2 ?

Comment: The code used in file2 is posted up on the question, but do not preocupeslo have solved another way and I think it works all right.

To refer to the activated div, I have obtained the id of the div using an attribute and so I could reference the current div: "var elemento=$("#tabs>div[aria-hidden='false']").attr("id");  $("#"+elemento).load(this.href);"Anyway, thanks for everything.