# Jquery return ajax undefined

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml

I am making a website in Jquery. Here I m trying to **parse an xml**.
I've got one file m_xml.js who get my xml and the c_parseXml.js who will parse it.
But I **can't get the file to the parse.js file**
look :

```js
function test() {
    RameneXml(function(output) {
        return output;
    });
}

function RameneXml(handleData) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "web/xml/calendrier.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        async: "false",
        success: function(xml) {
            handleData(xml);
        }
    });
}
```

It's my m_xml file. and with this file I want to get it in a variable.
look my file parseXml.js

```js
function DonnerDiffusion() {
    output = test();
    console.log(output);
}
```

but in the console I can see **undefined**

What have I do Wrong ?
Thanks

Comment: load jquery and then put your code inside ready function.

Comment: Your `test()` function doesn't return anything, hence `undefined`. Also, remove `async: false`. It's extremely bad practice to use it.

Comment: what ? but I wrote return output ? Sorry I beging jQuery. But the return statement do not apply ?

Comment: Yes - in the anonymous function you provide to `RameneXml()`. Nothing is returned from `test()`

Comment: so what should I do if I want to return something from test() ?

Comment: I don't see the point of your `test()` function. It just wraps `RameneXml()`, so why not call that instead, and put your logic that deals with the XML response in the callback?

Comment: See the question I marked as duplicate for more information. You've already solved the problem once in your code by passing the callback function to `RameneXml()`. You need to follow the same pattern for `test()` - or remove it completely as it seems pretty redundant at the moment.

Comment: yes, because I have understand than I can't do a return in my ajax function

Comment: So how could I call it on the parseXml.js if I can return anything

Comment: $Blinkix: what do u mean by the `output = test();` in **DonnerDiffusion() ** and you have used it as a parameter in RameneXml()? I think you don't need recursive methods to do this

Comment: in fact I would like to have a var exemple output that contains my xml. And here I print it in the console to see if it work

Comment: Make thhe funtion DonnerDiffusionas`function DonnerDiffusion() {
     var output = test();
    console.log(output);
}`    mention what you want to archieve clearly...                   if you want to run the function after ajax call use                                                                              `$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
  $( ".log" ).text( "Triggered ajaxComplete handler." );
});`

Comment: I'm not sure I clearly understand what you want to say ... sorry

Comment: As I have understood you need to pass result of one ajax function data to another function isn't it? Am I right?

Comment: yes and this other function is on another page

Comment: So I think what you need to do is pass variable from one js to another js?       [have a look here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29686004/how-can-i-pass-a-variable-from-one-js-file-to-another-js)

Comment: thanks for your help but I finally change some thing and I've done it on js Thanks a lot